# Update any variable in a function from different classes

Tags: c#, function, controls

In my Main Class I have a variable, for example

```
DataRow TestRow;
```

I'm sending this to a function: `EditDataRow(TestRow);`

```
EditDataRow(DataRow abc)      
{
   // Changing some abc Properties value, text etc.
}
```

Now I want to see `abc` and `TestRow` are same. When abc changes, TestRow should change too. They should be like Clone of themselves. How can I do that? I dont want to do like

```
TestRow = EditDataRow(TestRow);
```

I hope that I could explain the situation properly

Comment: Ok. Edited the question

Comment: what is `abc`? Is it something on your UI that when you change you want to change in your DataRow?  If it is a UI element, what kind are you using (i.e. wpf, form, etc)

Comment: abc is just a parameter of course it will always equals TestRow or whatever input you gvie the method

Comment: improved spelling and grammar

Answer (score 0):

Use **[Pass By Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14akc2c7)**.

```
class RefExample 
{
    static void Method(ref int i)
    {
        i = i + 44;
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        int val = 1;
        Method(ref val);
        Console.WriteLine(val);

        // Output: 45
    }
}
```

So in your example, it would be:

```
EditDataRow(ref DataRow abc)
{
   // Changing some abc Properties value, text etc.
}
```

And the call:

```
EditDataRow(ref TestRow);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make your own [extension](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx) method.

```
public static void EditDataRow(this DataRow dataRow) {
  // Changing some abc Properties value, text etc.
}
```

And then call it:

```
TestRow.EditDataRow():
```